# Change UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey on the go?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

Is it possible to change this value in the UIPageViewController as I browse through the pages so I can connect odd and even pages accordingly as they are in a real magazine?

I know this can be modified when you initialise the controller ...

Comment: have you found any solution for this , any help will be great ?

Comment: unfortunately not ...